# Using Twig render engine with Express

Tags: node.js, express, templating, twig.js

I've decided to make the jump from building my websites with slim, php and twig to using node.js and express.

To limit the shock of changing my whole process I want to keep using slim as the template engine instead of the default jade.

I have tried to change the code to change the render engine over to twig but now I am getting the following error message. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I am at a loss as to why it is not working. Any help would be very helpful.

**Error message:**

> Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "/var/www/html/SocialTrackers/app/views"
> at Function.render (/var/www/html/SocialTrackers/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:580:17)
> at ServerResponse.render (/var/www/html/SocialTrackers/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1008:7)
> at /var/www/html/SocialTrackers/app/app.js:38:7
> at Layer.handle_error (/var/www/html/SocialTrackers/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5)
> at trim_prefix (/var/www/html/SocialTrackers/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:315:13)
> at /var/www/html/SocialTrackers/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
> at Function.process_params (/var/www/html/SocialTrackers/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
> at next (/var/www/html/SocialTrackers/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
> at Layer.handle_error (/var/www/html/SocialTrackers/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:67:12)
> at trim_prefix (/var/www/html/SocialTrackers/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:315:13)

This is the code I am currently running. Other than changes to shift over the using twig as the render engine, I have made no other changes to the initial express install.

**app.js**

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var twig = require("twig");
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, './views'));
app.set('view engine', 'twig');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/bootstrap', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/'))

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
 // set locals, only providing error in development
 res.locals.message = err.message;
 res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

 // render the error page
 res.status(err.status || 500);
 res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**Additionally, I am the following file structure (default express)**

```
app
--bin 
--node_modules
--public
--routes
----index.js
----users.js
--views
----error.twig
----index.twig
----landingpage.twig
--app.js
```

Comment: Have you tried the [wiki entry for Express](https://github.com/twigjs/twig.js/wiki#appjs)?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, figured it out thanks.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working but there is absolutely no way anyone here could have answered this from the details in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a few days to figure this one out.

As I said I'm new to Nodejs and express so I believe I made a very rookie mistake. I thought I would post the solution incase anyone else has this issue.

I was running the node server on a ec2 instance. While I was updating the code it turns out I had to restart the node server as well.

I'm using pm2 to keep the server running all the time so for me the solution was to run the following command.

```
pm2 restart [namespace of server]
```

Note: for me, I never gave the server a namespace so it was simply 'default'. If you don't know the namespace you can find it by running 'pm2 list'

```
pm2 restart default
```